# merge two dataframe columns into 1 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns in my data frame and I need to merge it into 1 single column

```
Index  A             Index   B
0      A             0       NAN
1      NAN           1       D
2      B             2       NAN
3      NAN           3       E
4      C             4       NAN
```

there will always be one 1 value across the Columns, i want my result to look like

```
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
```

Answer (score 9):

***Option 1***

```
df.stack().dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

0    A
1    D
2    B
3    E
4    C
dtype: object
```

***Option 2***
If Missing values are always alternating

```
df.A.combine_first(df.B)

Index
0    A
1    D
2    B
3    E
4    C
Name: A, dtype: object
```

***Option 3***
What you asked for

```
df.A.append(df.B).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
dtype: object
```

***Option 4***
Similar to 3 but over arbitrary number of columns

```
pd.concat([i for _, i in df.iteritems()]).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
dtype: object
```