# How to merge/combine columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multiple-columns

I have a (example-) dataframe with 4 columns:

```
data = {'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    'B': [42, 52, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],  
    'C': [np.nan, np.nan, 31, 2, np.nan, np.nan],
    'D': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

    A   B       C       D
0   a   42.0    NaN     NaN
1   b   52.0    NaN     NaN
2   c   NaN     31.0    NaN
3   d   NaN     2.0     NaN
4   e   NaN     NaN     62.0
5   f   NaN     NaN     70.0
```

I would now like to merge/combine columns B, C, and D to a new column E like in this example:

```
data2 = {'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    'E': [42, 52, 31, 2, 62, 70]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['A', 'E'])

    A   E
0   a   42
1   b   52
2   c   31
3   d   2
4   e   62
5   f   70
```

I found a quite similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276249/merge-two-dataframe-columns-into-1-in-pandas) but this adds the merged colums B, C, and D at the end of column A:

```
0      a
1      b
2      c
3      d
4      e
5      f
6     42
7     52
8     31
9      2
10    62
11    70
dtype: object
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What happens if both B and C have values in them? Which one do you intend to retain in E?

Comment: Good question - the second option of jezrael further down accounts for this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Option 1**
Using `assign` and `drop`

```
In [644]: cols = ['B', 'C', 'D']

In [645]: df.assign(E=df[cols].sum(1)).drop(cols, 1)
Out[645]:
   A     E
0  a  42.0
1  b  52.0
2  c  31.0
3  d   2.0
4  e  62.0
5  f  70.0
```

---

**Option 2**
Using assignment and `drop`

```
In [648]: df['E'] = df[cols].sum(1)

In [649]: df = df.drop(cols, 1)

In [650]: df
Out[650]:
   A     E
0  a  42.0
1  b  52.0
2  c  31.0
3  d   2.0
4  e  62.0
5  f  70.0
```

---

**Option 3** Lately, I like the 3rd option.
Using `groupby`

```
In [660]: df.groupby(np.where(df.columns == 'A', 'A', 'E'), axis=1).first() #or sum max min
Out[660]:
   A     E
0  a  42.0
1  b  52.0
2  c  31.0
3  d   2.0
4  e  62.0
5  f  70.0

In [661]: df.columns == 'A'
Out[661]: array([ True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [662]: np.where(df.columns == 'A', 'A', 'E')
Out[662]:
array(['A', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: Option 1 worked perfectly. I would tend to prefer opt. 1 and opt. 2, most likely because of their simplicity... Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The question as written asks for merge/combine as opposed to sum, so posting this to help folks who find this answer looking for help on coalescing with combine_first, which can be a bit tricky.

```
df2 = pd.concat([df["A"], 
             df["B"].combine_first(df["C"]).combine_first(df["D"])], 
            axis=1)
df2.rename(columns={"B":"E"}, inplace=True)
   A     E
0  a  42.0
1  b  52.0
2  c  31.0
3  d  2.0 
4  e  62.0
5  f  70.0
```

What's so tricky about that?   in this case there's no problem - but let's say you were pulling the B, C and D values from different dataframes, in which the a,b,c,d,e,f labels were present, but not necessarily in the same order.    combine_first() aligns on the index, so you'd need to tack a set_index() on to each of your df references.

```
df2 = pd.concat([df.set_index("A", drop=False)["A"], 
             df.set_index("A")["B"]\
             .combine_first(df.set_index("A")["C"])\
             .combine_first(df.set_index("A")["D"]).astype(int)], 
            axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df2.rename(columns={"B":"E"}, inplace=True)

   A   E
0  a  42
1  b  52
2  c  31
3  d  2 
4  e  62
5  f  70
```

Comment: This answer works for strings, not just numbers (unlike those using `sum()`).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) for columns names without `A` and then get `sum` or `max`:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['A'])
df['E'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1).astype(int)
# df['E'] = df[cols].max(axis=1).astype(int)
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
   A   E
0  a  42
1  b  52
2  c  31
3  d   2
4  e  62
5  f  70
```

If multiple values per rows:

```
data = {'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    'B': [42, 52, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],  
    'C': [np.nan, np.nan, 31, 2, np.nan, np.nan],
    'D': [10, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

print (df)
   A     B     C     D
0  a  42.0   NaN  10.0
1  b  52.0   NaN   NaN
2  c   NaN  31.0   NaN
3  d   NaN   2.0   NaN
4  e   NaN   NaN  62.0
5  f   NaN   NaN  70.0

cols = df.columns.difference(['A'])
df['E'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str)), 1)
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
   A       E
0  a  42, 10
1  b      52
2  c      31
3  d       2
4  e      62
5  f      70
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael helpful indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Zero's third option using `groupby` requires a numpy import and only handles one column outside the set of columns to collapse, while jpp's answer using `ffill` requires you know how columns are ordered. Here's a solution that has no extra dependencies, takes an arbitrary input dataframe, and only collapses columns if all rows in those columns are single-valued:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [{'A':'a', 'B':42, 'messy':'z'},
    {'A':'b', 'B':52, 'messy':'y'},
    {'A':'c', 'C':31},
    {'A':'d', 'C':2, 'messy':'w'},
    {'A':'e', 'D':62, 'messy':'v'},
    {'A':'f', 'D':70, 'messy':['z']}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

cols = ['B', 'C', 'D']
new_col = 'E'
if df[cols].apply(lambda x: len(x.notna().value_counts()) == 1, axis=1).all():
    df[new_col] = df[cols].ffill(axis=1).dropna(axis=1)

df2 = df.drop(columns=cols)

print(df, '\n\n', df2)
```

Output:

```py
   A     B messy     C     D
0  a  42.0     z   NaN   NaN
1  b  52.0     y   NaN   NaN
2  c   NaN   NaN  31.0   NaN
3  d   NaN     w   2.0   NaN
4  e   NaN     v   NaN  62.0
5  f   NaN   [z]   NaN  70.0

   A messy     E
0  a     z  42.0
1  b     y  52.0
2  c   NaN  31.0
3  d     w   2.0
4  e     v  62.0
5  f   [z]  70.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ffill` with `iloc`:

```
df['E'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].ffill(1).iloc[:, -1].astype(int)
df = df.iloc[:, [0, -1]]

print(df)

   A   E
0  a  42
1  b  52
2  c  31
3  d   2
4  e  62
5  f  70
```