# split dataframe and combine into one column python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has two columns "0" and "1" there some values and NA in both columns I want to basically combine into one column since the row names are either "edible" and "poisonous". how do i do this in python?

[here is the image of the data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ6M8.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge/combine columns in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563833/how-to-merge-combine-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1

`df.sum(axis=1)`

#### Solution 2

`df['0'].fillna(df['1'])`